# Retrieve the pixel values of an image with Haskell

Tags: haskell, image-processing, libraries, image-recognition

Is there a way or a library available that can load an image (jpeg, png, etc) and assign the pixel values of that image into a list or matrix? I'd like to do some experiments with image and pattern recognition.

A little nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the [repa-devil](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-devil-0.3.2.1) package for this in the past. It lets you work with a bunch of formats using Developer's Image Library (DevIL). You can read and write all the formats you are likely to care about.

The actual image data is given as a [Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.2.2.2) array. This is a great library for array operations and makes it very easy to write parallel code.

Comment: Just a note to self (and others): The "Missing C library: IL" is likely libdevil-dev.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JuicyPixels, a native Haskell library for image loading.  This is rather easy to convert to REPA as well (manually or with JuicyPixesl-repa).

Comment: Thomas, would you happen to know where I could find some usage examples? The documentation is reading very cryptically for me.

Comment: I can't help much without knowing the task.  I suggest starting with `func file = onImg someRepaFunction \`fmap\` readImage file`.  Using  that line you should only need to define `someRepaFunction`.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you. I don't know what a repa is, and I can't get repa-devil to install in Windows because of some -dev C library dependency. My patience has finally ran out. I like Haskell, but I can't deal with this anymore. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Repa is an array library, there are tutorials you can find online - one linked in the below answer.  If you are looking for more real-time help then I suggest you try IRC (#haskell on freenode.net)

Answer (score 3):

Try the [repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) library
.Also there is a small tutorial [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial)

Comment: Very helpful tutorial. I've saved it for offline viewing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a new [Haskell Image Processing library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip), which uses JuicyPixels for encoding, provides interface for you to read and write all of the supported formats in a very easy manner and manipulate them in any way you can imagine. Just as a simple example on how easy it is:

```
>>> img <- readImageRGB "image.jpg"
>>> writeImage "image90.png" $ rotate90 img
```

Above will read a JPG image in RGB color space, rotate it 90 degrees clockwise and save it as a PNG image.

Oh yeah, it also can use Repa, so you will get parallel processing for free as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. GTK supports loading and saving JPEG and PNG. [AFAIK, no other formats though.] There is a Haskell binding named `Gtk2hs`. It supports *vector* graphics very well, but *bitmap* graphics, while supported, isn't especially easy to figure out. So I wrote `AC-EasyRaster-GTK`, which wraps GTK in a more friendly interface. (It still needs `Gtk2hs` though.) The only real down-side is that `Gtk2h` is a bit fiddly to set up on Windows. (And it's arguably overkill to install an entire GUI toolkit just to load and save image files.)
2. I gather the "GD" library supports writing several image formats, and is quite small and simple. I believe Hackage has Haskell bindings for GD as well. I haven't tried this personally.
3. There is a file format called PPM which is deliberately designed to be ridiculously easy to implement (it's a tiny header and then an array of pixels), and consequently there's at least a dozen packages on Hackage which implement it (including my own `AC-PPM`). There are also lots of programs out there which can display and/or convert images in this format.